# Copy-Item problem with destination

Tags: powershell, command

I have two Copy-Item commands

1. `Copy-Item "C:\Test\folder1" "\\remote_machine\destination" -Recurse`
2. `Copy-Item "C:\Test\folder2" "\\remote_machine\destination" -Recurse`

folder1 and folder2 contain folders and files

Both commands are similar, but I get different results

1. Copy content of folder1 to destination - OK
2. Copy folder2  with all content to destination - \remote_machine\destination\folder2 - FAIL

UPDATE: I don't get any error. Problem is about path to second folder. I want content of both folders in one destination folder.

Comment: it is probably the contents of folder2 that is causing the error. What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's problem with PowerShell - http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/browse_frm/thread/ae9b8b4424c2af22

Solution for my examples is

1. `Copy-Item "C:\Test\folder1" "\\remote_machine\destination" -Recurse`
2. `Copy-Item "C:\Test\folder2\*" "\\remote_machine\destination" -Recurse`